# Install cuda driver in an virtual container of proxmox

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, openvz

I have installed `2.6.32-17-pve` on my host machine with:

```
    02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 11c6 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device 3557
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at fb000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
```

After creating a virtual container of ubuntu 12.04, I tried to install cuda-driver as follow:

1. `vzctl set 100 --pci_add 02:00.0` on host, and `lspci -v` in vz print:

   ```
   02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 11c6 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
   Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device 3557
   Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
   Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
   Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
   Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
   I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
   Expansion ROM at fb000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
   Capabilities: <access denied>
   Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb
   ```
2. I install the recommended packages for installing cuda, and change the gcc version to 4.4
3. To install the kernel header of pve, I add the sources.list of pve: `deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian squeeze pve` and run `sudo apt-get install pve-headers-2.6.32-17-pve`
4. Now I am trying to install the driver, but:

   ```
   ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most
   frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or
   improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that
   differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if a driver
   such as rivafb, nvidiafb, or nouveau is present and prevents the
   NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA graphics
   device(s), or NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is not supported
   by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.
   ```

I guess the reason might be that the vz does not obtain ownership of the graphics device, but I am not sure and do not know how to fix it. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a vz user ,but it seems to me like the problem is in the client - it looks like the nvidia driver is not being found/loaded by the kernel you are using - maybe you need to install the nvidia module in the virtual host ?

Comment: Have you tried the dual method which consists in installing the nvidia driver in the host and then *sharing* ``/dev/nvidia0`` with the guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading of kernel modules is prohibited from inside OpenVZ containers: it's a security measure since kernel is shared between host and all containers.

What *might* work: load the required kernel drivers on the host, add access to any associated devices using --devnodes and just in case enable all capabilities using --capability